# python readline by '\r\n'

Tags: python, io

How can I called `f.readline()` where the line delimeter is `\r\n` ?

This CSV file is very large so I can't do `f.read().split('\r\n')`.

Instead I'm hoping for `f.readline('\r\n')`.

Here is a typical line:

```
1, "ABC", "the quick \n brown fox \n jumps over the \n lazy dogs", 5 \r\n
```

Comment: Why do you want to specify that delimiter manually? `readline` should use it automatically by default.

Comment: I want `readline` to ignore `\n` and use only `\r\n`

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237246/python-how-to-read-file-with-nul-delimited-lines

Comment: this file is 8GB, I can't `split`.  Perhaps I an read a few lines `split` and keep the remainder

Comment: Are there really spaces after each comma?

Comment: use [`io.open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io#io.open) to open the file and specify the `newline` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're actually trying to read a CSV file (or something like it) where newlines that are embedded in quotes need to be ignored.

That's something the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) already handles for you.

```
import csv
with open("myfile", "rb") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=",", skipinitialspaces=True)
    for line in reader:
       print line
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use `csv`, then [open](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) the file with [*universal newlines support*](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines):

```
f = open('big_csv_file.csv', 'rU')
```

This will cause `f.readline()` to interpret `\n`, `\r\n` and `\r` equally, each as a newline.

Answer (score 0):

From the csv [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|') #<--- Note the
                                                                       #delimiter param.
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Just make a csvreader with delimiter set to '\r\n'. That should give you each line delimited
by \r\n.